# Viewing Application files on Android

Tags: android, windows

I have a rooted HTC device, and I want to access the /data/app/ directory on my phone to fix a bug, and I am looking for a way to do this from my PC rather than creating a new emulated environment just to fix that bug. It lead to a looping lock screen, where every three seconds I would end up at the lock screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have USB debugging enabled, you can try to open "adb shell" and inside of it get root permissions using "su" command. After that you can open any file in any folder through this shell window. Moving in between folders the same as in a Linux, and it's easy to Google how to do that.